# How to set data in Model?

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, repository, android-room

I have one entity "drinks" which have [id;name;thumb] and I`m using these entities for 2 response calls. One response returns me a NonAlcohol list of drinks, another AlcoholList, I'm using Room for caching the data. But when I run the app, I saw that my lists merged, after some thought, I found a solution to this problem, I added one Boolean field to my entity "alcoholStatus".But I can't understand how to set the data into this variable correctly using this AccessDataStrategy. I'm new to Android, and this is my learning project. Please give me the right way how to solve this problem.

https://github.com/YaroslavSulyma/LetsDrink/tree/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/letsdrink

Thanks a lot!

Entity

```
@Entity(tableName = "drinks")
data class DrinksModel(
    @SerializedName("strDrink")
    val strDrink: String,
    @SerializedName("strDrinkThumb")
    val strDrinkThumb: String?,
    @SerializedName("idDrink")
    @PrimaryKey
    val idDrink: Int,
    var alcohol: Boolean
)
```

DataAccessStrategyCode

```
fun <T, A> performGetOperation(
    databaseQuery: () -> LiveData<T>,
    networkCall: suspend () -> Resource<A>,
    saveCallResult: suspend (A) -> Unit
): LiveData<Resource<T>> =
    liveData(Dispatchers.IO) {
        emit(Resource.loading())
        val source = databaseQuery.invoke().map { Resource.success(it) }
        emitSource(source)

        val responseStatus = networkCall.invoke()
        if (responseStatus.status == SUCCESS) {
            saveCallResult(responseStatus.data!!)

        } else if (responseStatus.status == ERROR) {
            emit(Resource.error(responseStatus.message!!))
            emitSource(source)
        }
    }
```

Resource

```
data class Resource<out T>(val status: Status, val data: T?, val message: String?) {

    enum class Status {
        SUCCESS,
        ERROR,
        LOADING
    }

    companion object {
        fun <T> success(data: T): Resource<T> {
            return Resource(Status.SUCCESS, data, null)
        }

        fun <T> error(message: String, data: T? = null): Resource<T> {
            return Resource(Status.ERROR, data, message)
        }

        fun <T> loading(data: T? = null): Resource<T> {
            return Resource(Status.LOADING, data, null)
        }
    }
}
```

Repository

```
class CocktailsRepository @Inject constructor(
        private val remoteDataSource: CocktailsRemoteDataSource,
        private val localDataSource: CocktailsDao
) {
        fun getAlcoholicCocktails() = performGetOperation(
            databaseQuery = { localDataSource.getAlcoholicCocktails() },
            networkCall = { remoteDataSource.getAllAlcoholicCocktails()},
            saveCallResult = { localDataSource.insertAllDrinks(it.drinks) }
        )
    
        fun getNonAlcoholicCocktails() = performGetOperation(
            databaseQuery = { localDataSource.getNonAlcoholicCocktails() },
            networkCall = { remoteDataSource.getAllNonAlcoholicCocktails() },
            saveCallResult = { localDataSource.insertAllDrinks(it.drinks) }
        )
    }
```

DAO

```
@Dao
interface CocktailsDao {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM drinks WHERE alcohol = 'true'")
    fun getAlcoholicCocktails(): LiveData<List<DrinksModel>>

    @Query("SELECT * FROM drinks WHERE alcohol = 'false'")
    fun getNonAlcoholicCocktails(): LiveData<List<DrinksModel>>

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    suspend fun insertAllDrinks(drinks: List<DrinksModel>)
}
```

RemoteDataSource

```
class CocktailsRemoteDataSource @Inject constructor(private val iCocktailApisService: ICocktailApisService) :
    BaseDataSource() {

    suspend fun getAllAlcoholicCocktails() =
        getResult { iCocktailApisService.allAlcoholicAndNonAlcoholicCocktails("Alcoholic") }

    suspend fun getAllNonAlcoholicCocktails() =
        getResult { iCocktailApisService.allAlcoholicAndNonAlcoholicCocktails("Non_Alcoholic") }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First:** I strongly recommend that you define separate data classes for your remote and local model classes and do the mapping between them when needed, for example:

Remote data model:

```
data class DrinkRemoteModel(
    @SerializedName("idDrink")
    val idDrink: Int,
    @SerializedName("strDrink")
    val strDrink: String,
    @SerializedName("strDrinkThumb")
    val strDrinkThumb: String?,
    @SerializedName("alcohol")
    var alcohol: Boolean
)
```

Local data model:

```
@Entity(tableName = "drinks")
data class DrinkLocalModel(
@PrimaryKey
    @ColumnInfo(name = "idDrink")
    val idDrink: Int,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "strDrink")
    val strDrink: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "strDrinkThumb")
    val strDrinkThumb: String?,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "alcohol")
    var alcohol: Boolean
)
```

**Back to your implementation:** I think what causing the problem is that **Room** maps Boolean fields in your entity to an integer column, `1` for `true`, and `0` for `false`, so try changing your querys in your DAO like following:

```
@Dao
interface CocktailsDao {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM drinks WHERE alcohol = 1")
    fun getAlcoholicCocktails(): LiveData<List<DrinksModel>>

    @Query("SELECT * FROM drinks WHERE alcohol = 0")
    fun getNonAlcoholicCocktails(): LiveData<List<DrinksModel>>

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    suspend fun insertAllDrinks(drinks: List<DrinksModel>)
}
```

**Alternatively:** you can substitute your `getAlcoholicCocktails` and `getNonAlcoholicCocktails` with one DAO function, like this:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM drinks WHERE alcohol = :isAlcoholic")
fun getCocktails(isAlcoholic : Boolean = true): LiveData<List<DrinksModel>>
```

Comment: That's a good answer, but I can't figure out how and where I can fill the "alcohol" field. 
1)Restore data from local DB
2)If DB is empty, I should get data from API
3)Save data from the response into local DB
But API doesn't return alcohol status and I can't understand where I can fill this field (where it'll be correctly? in the repository? in a remote module or local?). I understand that this may be a stupid question, but I can't figure out how to do it right.

Comment: I believe this logic should reside in your repository, as it's the component responsible for fetch and save strategies

Comment: I think you should set this boolean value of your items within `saveCallResult`, in other words, the rows in your DB always contains the correct `alcoholic` boolean value

Comment: I did something like this:
`@Query("SELECT * FROM drinks WHERE alcohol =:isAlcohol")
    fun getAllDrinks(isAlcohol: Boolean): LiveData<List<DrinksModel>>

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    suspend fun insertAllDrinks(drinks: List<DrinksModel>, isAlcohol: Boolean) {
        for (drink in drinks) drink.alcohol = isAlcohol
    }`

But now getAllDrinks query return null I don't know why it happens, saveCallResult saves correct data. I thought maybe the wrong query and tried to get all list without alcohol status, but I have null again

Comment: I don't think it's right to add implementation for DAO functions, instead use your previous `insertAllDrinks` implementation like this, (in your Repository) :  `saveCallResult = { localDataSource.insertAllDrinks(it.drinks.forEach { it.alcohol = true /* or false */}) }`

Comment: I tried to do it, but this implementation return Unit instead of List<DrinksModel>

Comment: You're right I'm sorry, then use `apply` , like this: `it.drinks.apply{  forEach{ .... } }`

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot! You're the best!
Also we can use onEach{} instead apply{foreach{}}

Comment: You're right `onEach` works as well (thumb-up).